# Catching exceptions with Log4j

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine, exception, dashboard

What is the log4j.category.DataNucleus for exceptions? So I wam trying to use Log4j with Google App Engine, however during testing the exceptions are not being picked up by Lo4j (they are being picked upby the dashboard).

Also I want all the errors to be picked up. So I have added this to the main class. Will this pick up all errors including fatel?

```
   logger.fatal ("App Error");
```

Ok so I tried this :

```
 }
     catch(Exception e) {
            logger.warn("Log4j has caught n exception!", e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

However the exception shows in the dashboard, but it's not log4j that is picking it up as it doesn't give me "Log4j has caught n exception!".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What is the log4j.category.DataNucleus for exceptions?**

```
log4j.logger.DataNucleus
```

**General**

I do not use Eclise nor Log4J (except that DataNucleus uses it, of course). I have the following in my log configuration files.

**log4j.properties**

```
log4j.appender.A1 = org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern = %d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} (%t) %-5p [%c] - %m%n

[...]

# Tighten logging on the DataNucleus categories to WARN.
# This DataNucleus logging configuration appears redundant; in production,
# DataNucleus uses Java logging instead.
log4j.logger.DataNucleus                 = WARN, A1
log4j.logger.DataNucleus.JDO             = WARN, A1
log4j.logger.DataNucleus.Persistence     = WARN, A1
log4j.logger.DataNucleus.Query           = WARN, A1
log4j.logger.DataNucleus.Lifecycle       = WARN, A1
log4j.logger.DataNucleus.Cache           = WARN, A1
log4j.logger.DataNucleus.MetaData        = WARN, A1
log4j.logger.DataNucleus.Management      = WARN, A1
log4j.logger.DataNucleus.General         = WARN, A1
log4j.logger.DataNucleus.Connection      = WARN, A1
log4j.logger.DataNucleus.Transaction     = WARN, A1
log4j.logger.DataNucleus.Datastore       = WARN, A1
log4j.logger.DataNucleus.ClassLoading    = WARN, A1
log4j.logger.DataNucleus.Plugin          = WARN, A1
log4j.logger.DataNucleus.ValueGeneration = WARN, A1
log4j.logger.DataNucleus.Enhancer        = WARN, A1
log4j.logger.DataNucleus.SchemaTool      = WARN, A1
```

**logging.properties**

```
handlers = java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.level = ALL
java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter

[...]

# Set the default logging level for ORM, specifically, to WARNING
DataNucleus.level                 = WARNING
DataNucleus.JDO.level             = WARNING
DataNucleus.Persistence.level     = WARNING
DataNucleus.Query.level           = WARNING
DataNucleus.Lifecycle.level       = WARNING
DataNucleus.Cache.level           = WARNING
DataNucleus.MetaData.level        = WARNING
DataNucleus.Management.level      = WARNING
DataNucleus.General.level         = WARNING
DataNucleus.Connection.level      = WARNING
DataNucleus.Transaction.level     = WARNING
DataNucleus.Datastore.level       = WARNING
DataNucleus.ClassLoading.level    = WARNING
DataNucleus.Plugin.level          = WARNING
DataNucleus.ValueGeneration.level = WARNING
DataNucleus.Enhancer.level        = WARNING
DataNucleus.SchemaTool.level      = WARNING
```

**logger.fatal ("App Error");**

I have never coded Log4J. Will this command not just log an entry of text `"App Error"` at the fatal level?

Enjoy?

Comment: If you feel that my answer is useful (you have ticked it!) then please feel free to give me a vote for its usefulness.